# Keep information local to branch

Tags: git, gitlab, branch

Does git or gitlab support to keep files/properties *local* to a specific branch?

With this, I mean that I have this information available in the branch (either as file, or as properties, or similar), but if I merge the branch back to master, this information is not merged back.

Use cases would be for testing with different configuration/servers/... than on master.

Comment: Have you taken a look to https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#_merge_strategies ?

Comment: @Ôrel Sounds nice. I need to figure out it if it can be used for GitLab merge requests.

Comment: Note that if you use the *branch name* to trigger inclusion of a specific file (`config.main`, `config.develop`, etc., you can get the effect you want. The branch name itself is not part of the *commit* but it will do the job.